# Undefined reference when linking a prebuilt shared library inside AOSP 7.1

Tags: android, shared-libraries, linker-errors, android-source, android.mk

I am adding a module inside the AOSP 7.1, and in there I want to use a prebuilt shared library that I generated with cmake via android-toolchain in Ndk. But when I want to use that module, I get undefined reference.

I also tried to change my lib to static but I still got the same error.

This is the module that I use the prebuilt libdump_android.so

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libdump_android
LOCAL_SRC_FILE := lib/../libdump_android.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/../dump
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is the module that I use the module

```
LOCAL_MODULE := libdump
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/../dump/dump.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libdump_android
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L lib/../dump_android -ldump_android
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is the the dump_android.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class DumpAndroid
{
    public:
    DumpAndroid();
    ~DumpAndroid() = default;
    void scream(void) const;
};
```

This is the dump_android.cpp:

```cpp
#include "dump_android.h"

DumpAndroid::DumpAndroid()
{
    std::cout << "DumpAndroid Constructed\n";
}

void DumpAndroid::scream(void) const
{
    std::cout << "DumpAndroid SCREAM \n";
}
```

This is the dump.h * (the src file inside that uses the prebuilt)

```cpp
#include <dump_android.h>

class Dump
{
   int dump_value;
   DumpAndroid dump_android_;

public:

  Dump();
  ~Dump() = default;

  void init(void);
};
```

This is the dump.cpp

```cpp
#include "dump.h"
Dump::Dump(){ }

void Dump::init(void)
{
  this->dump_value = 15;
  dump_android_.scream();
}
```

This is the cmake command that I build with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/Android/Ndk/android-ndk-r19c/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a"
```

When I build the module, I get the error:

### "error: undefined reference to "DumpAndroid::DumpAndroid()""

### "error: undefined reference to "DumpAndroid::screa() const""

I know my device is an arm64-v8a for sure.

Comment: The code you posted for `LOCAL_MODULE := libdump` is a fragment of an **Android.mk** file, that expects to be built with **ndk-build**, not with **cmake**.

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for replying, yes that module is a fragment of Android.mk and  have e dependency in my prebuilt module which is libdump_android, which I add it in the Android.mk "toolchain" as documentation says!

Comment: So, all is working now?

Comment: No there is still that problem! I didn't change anything, this state is from the beginning.

Comment: You have an **Android.mk** file that uses prebuilt **libdump_android.so** and produces **libdump.so**. Why do you run **cmake**?

Comment: I generate the libdump_android.so with cmake, and than I want to link it and use it with the inside module libdump.so. libdump.so is an internal module that uses this prebuilt, there is my issue I have this linker error.